I'm having issues with the error: " 'int' object not interable "error while trying to make a lottery system in Python
I'm trying to make a lottery system in Python using the following code:
failed = True
passed = False
number_of_tickets = []
ticket_num = []
ticket_cost = int(10)
ticket_cost_sum = 0
randomly_generated_num = []
final_ticket = []

ticket_sum_inquiry = (int(input("Enter number of tickets: ")))
ticket_sum_inquiry
print (ticket_sum_inquiry)

print ("It will cost", ticket_sum_inquiry*ticket_cost, "dollars for these tickets.")

import random
def randint(min=1,max=100):
    randomly_generated_num = random.randint(min,max)
    return randomly_generated_num

randint()
ticket_num.append(randomly_generated_num)
   

Proceed = input('Would you like to continue? enter "y" for yes, enter "n" no: ' )
if Proceed.lower() == "y":
  print ("Great, here are your tickets with their numbers:")
  for tickets, numbers in zip(ticket_sum_inquiry, ticket_num):
    print(tickets, ':', {randint(numbers)} )
elif Proceed.lower() == "n":
    print ("Goodbye")
else:

As you can see, the code is incomplete, as I've yet to implement the winning numbers for the lottery. However, along the way, I encountered a problem when trying to give the user their **tickets **along with generating the corresponding numbers to those tickets:
 for tickets, numbers in zip(ticket_sum_inquiry, ticket_num):
    print(tickets, ':', {randint(numbers)} )

Whenever I try to run this, Python returns:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

The error is exactly right.  ticket_sum_inquiry is an integer.  What were you expecting that to do?  Also note that you never save the return from your randint function, and the variable randomly_generated_num is local to the function and will go away.

Perhaps you wanted ticket_num = [random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(ticket_sum_inquiry)].

Python also tells you what line the error is coming from. That information should be included in your question.

The purpose of zip() is to join together two sequences.  But the first argument you passed to zip() is a single integer, not a sequence.

ticket_sum_inquiry = (int(input("Enter number of tickets: "))) - looks like an int

Thank you @TimRoberts, your solution worked.
